# Error: Reference to undeclared module on modules/site_recovery/main.tf

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created resource, network and compute module in terraform, now want to pass output of vm_id to site recovery module here are the files I am using currently.

Continue to subject: `in resource "azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm" "vm-replication": source_vm_id= module.compute.vm_id`

This is directory structure that I am following currently,

```
.
├── main.tf
└── modules
    ├── compute
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── outputs.tf_bk
    │   ├── variable.tf
    │   └── variable.tfvars
    ├── network
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── variable.tf
    │   └── variable.tfvars
    ├── resource
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── variable.tf
    │   └── variable.tfvars
    └── site_recovery
        ├── main.tf
        ├── variable.tf
        └── variable.tfvars
```

root module main.cf file:

```
#Select provider
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  version = "~> 2.4"
  features {}
}

module "resource" {
  source = "./modules/resource"
  resource_group_name = "devops_primary"
  location = "southeastasia"
}

module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"
  virtual_network = "primaryvnet"
  subnet = "primarysubnet"
  address_space = "192.168.0.0/16"
  address_prefix = "192.168.1.0/24"
  public_ip = "backendvmpip"
  location = "southeastasia"
  primary_nic = "backendvmnic"
  primary_ip_conf = "backendvm"
  resource_group_name = "module.resource.primary_group_name"
}

module "compute" {
  source = "./modules/compute"
  #resource_group_name = "devops_primary"
  #location = "southeastasia"
  vm_name = "backendvm-primary"
  vm_size = "standard_d2s_v3"
  vm_storage_od_disk_name = "backend-vm-os-disk-primary"
  computer_name = "backendserver"
  username = "terraform"
  ssh_key_path = "/home/terraform/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  keys_data = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
  sa_name = "primarysa"
  disk_name = "backenddisk_primary"
}

module "site_recovery" {
  source = "./modules/site_recovery"
  #resource_group_name = "devops_primary"
  #location = "southeastasia"
  sec_resource_group = "devops_secondary"
  recovery_vault_name = "recovery-vault"
  primary_fabric = "devops_primary-fabric"
  seconday_fabric = "devops_secondary-fabric"
  primary_container = "primary-protection-container"
  secondary_container = "secondary-protection-container"
  policy_name = "policy"
  container_mapping = "container-mapping"
  replicated_vm = "backendvm-replication"
}
```

compute main.cf :

```
#Create VM in Primary resource
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "primary" {
  name                  = "var.vm_name"
  location              = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location"
  resource_group_name   = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
  vm_size               = "var.vm_size"
  network_interface_ids = ["module.resource.azurerm_network_interface.primary.id"]

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "var.vm_storage_od_disk_name"
    os_type           = "Linux"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "var.computer_name"
    admin_username = "var.username"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true

  ssh_keys {
      path     = "/home/terraform/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      key_data = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
    }
  }
  tags = {
        environment = "Test"
    }
output "vm_ids" {
  description = "Virtual machine ids created."
  value       = azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.id
  #depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.primary]
}
```

site recovery main.cf

```
#Create Site Recovery Replicated VM
resource "azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm" "vm-replication" {
  name                                      = var.replicated_vm
  resource_group_name                       = azurerm_resource_group.secondary.name
  recovery_vault_name                       = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  source_recovery_fabric_name               = azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.primary.name
  #source_vm_id                              = site recovery main.cf

#Create Site Recovery Replicated VM
resource "azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm" "vm-replication" {
  name                                      = var.replicated_vm
  resource_group_name                       = azurerm_resource_group.secondary.name
  recovery_vault_name                       = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  source_recovery_fabric_name               = azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.primary.name
  #source_vm_id                              = "module.compute.azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.id"
  source_vm_id                              = module.compute.vm_ids
  recovery_replication_policy_id            = azurerm_site_recovery_replication_policy.policy.id
  source_recovery_protection_container_name = azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container.primary.name
  target_resource_group_id                  = azurerm_resource_group.secondary.id
  target_recovery_fabric_id                 = azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.secondary.id
  target_recovery_protection_container_id   = azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container.secondary.id


  managed_disk {
    disk_id                    = "[module.resource.azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.storage_os_disk[0].managed_disk_id]"
    staging_storage_account_id = "module.resource.azurerm_storage_account.primary.id"
    target_resource_group_id   = azurerm_resource_group.secondary.id
    target_disk_type           = "Premium_LRS"
    target_replica_disk_type   = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  managed_disk {
    disk_id                    = "[module.resource.azurerm_managed_disk.primary.id]"
    staging_storage_account_id = "[module.resource.azurerm_storage_account.primary.id]"
    target_resource_group_id   = azurerm_resource_group.secondary.id
    target_disk_type           = "Premium_LRS"
    target_replica_disk_type   = "Premium_LRS"
  }
depends_on = ["module.compute.vm_ids"]
}
```

Used depends_on for input to site_recovery module, again will you please suggest, how can I output managed disks ids and Os disks ids from compute module and use input in site recovery module.

Comment: I have added output to compute for vm id as below                                                                           `output "vm_ids" {
  description = "Virtual machine ids created."
  value       = azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.*.id
  #depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.primary]
}`

Comment: I have added output to compute for vm id (main.tf ) as below:                                                                           `output "vm_ids" {description = "Virtual machine ids created."
  value       = azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.*.id
}`                       and added vm_ids to site recovery module as :                                     
 `module "site_recovery" { vm_ids = "module.compute.vm_ids" } `                                    added variable to site_recovery module as :      
`"azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm" "vm-replication" { source_vm_id = var.vm_ids }`

Comment: With _terrform plan_ getting succes, but with _terraform plan getting below as same above                                                                                                                                      `Error: Can not parse "source_vm_id" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse module.compute.vm_ids: invalid URI for request

  on modules/site_recovery/main.tf line 80, in resource "azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm" "vm-replication":
  80: resource "azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm" "vm-replication" {` @Nancy Xiong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error

> Error: Reference to undeclared module on modules/site_recovery/main.tf

It means the referenced module is not declared in the calling module.

To call a module means to include the contents of that module into the configuration with specific values for its input variables. Modules are called from within other modules using `module` blocks. You need to add the `module` block in the configuration `.tf` file where you want to call that module. See [calling a child module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#calling-a-child-module).

It seems that there are no module blocks declared in your sub site recovery and compute `main.tf`, so you can not call the resource modules such as `module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location`, `module.resource.azurerm_managed_disk.primary.id` and so on.

As your directory structure, you can also use input variable to call the module from another module output. The correct expression is `module.<MODULE NAME>.<OUTPUT NAME>`.

To output the VM id and managed disks id from compute module like this:

```
output "azurerm_vm_id" {
  value = azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.id
}


output "primary_os_disk_id" {
  value = azurerm_virtual_machine.primary.storage_os_disk[0].managed_disk_id
}
```

The `main.tf` in the root directory

```
module "vm" {
  source = "./modules/vm"
  vm_name = "backendvm-primary"
  vm_size = "standard_d2s_v3"
  vm_storage_od_disk_name = "backend-vm-os-disk-primary"
  computer_name = "backendserver"
  username = "terraform"
  nic_ids = module.network.primary_nic_id
  resource_group_name = module.resource.rg_name
  location = module.resource.rg_location
  #ssh_key_path = "/home/terraform/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  #keys_data = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}


module "site_recovery" {
  source = "./modules/site_recovery"
  resource_group_name = module.resource.rg_name
  location = module.resource.rg_location
  sec_resource_group = "nancy_secondary"
  sec_location = "eastus"
  recovery_vault_name = "recovery-vault"
  primary_fabric = "devops_primary-fabric"
  seconday_fabric = "devops_secondary-fabric"
  primary_container = "primary-protection-container"
  secondary_container = "secondary-protection-container"
  policy_name = "policy"
  container_mapping = "container-mapping"
  replicated_vm = "backendvm-replication"

  source_vm_id  = module.vm.azurerm_vm_id
  primary_os_disk_id = module.vm.primary_os_disk_id

}
```

The Site Recovery main.tf file

```
#Create Site Recovery Replicated VM
resource "azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm" "vm-replication" {
  depends_on                                = [var.vm_depends_on]
  name                                      = var.replicated_vm
  resource_group_name                       = azurerm_resource_group.secondary.name
  recovery_vault_name                       = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  source_recovery_fabric_name               = azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.primary.name

  source_vm_id                              = var.source_vm_id
  recovery_replication_policy_id            = azurerm_site_recovery_replication_policy.policy.id
  source_recovery_protection_container_name = azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container.primary.name
  target_resource_group_id                  = azurerm_resource_group.secondary.id
  target_recovery_fabric_id                 = azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.secondary.id
  target_recovery_protection_container_id   = azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container.secondary.id


  managed_disk {
    disk_id                    = var.primary_os_disk_id
    staging_storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.primary.id
    target_resource_group_id   = azurerm_resource_group.secondary.id
    target_disk_type           = "Premium_LRS"
    target_replica_disk_type   = "Premium_LRS"
  }

}
```

In fact, in the `azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm` block, there is an implicit dependencies `source_vm_id`, it replys on the source Azure VM. If you want to use terraform `depends_on` meta-argument accepts a list of resources with module. You can refer to this thread - [Terraform depends_on with modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275233/terraform-depends-on-with-modules) and [this document](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/azure/dependencies_az).