# Dependency issue with multiple Terraform modules deploying to Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, terraform

I'm trying to deploy a few modules in a Terraform pipeline, to Azure. I've deployed the dev pipeline while developing it, so I added the first resource / module, deployed it, then the next, deployed again, in a for me logical order. Now, I'm trying to reuse all my code with an other variable file, for a test environment. But, I notice I'm getting dependency errors on when deploying.

This is what I'm getting:

```
│ Error: Application Insights "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" (Resource Group "xxxxxxxxxxx") was not found
│ 
│   with module.mongodb.data.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights["api"],
│   on modules\mongodb\data.tf line 4, in data "azurerm_application_insights" "app_insights":
│    4: data "azurerm_application_insights" "app_insights" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: Linux Web App: (Site Name "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" / Resource Group "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") not found
│ 
│   with module.mongodb.data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps["api"],
│   on modules\mongodb\data.tf line 22, in data "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web_apps":
│   22: data "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web_apps" {
│ 
│ Linux Web App: (Site Name "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" / Resource Group
│ "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") not found
```

So it's telling me the application insights and webapp aren't existing yet when the mongodb is deployed, which needs some of the details of those resources. At start time this is indeed correct, but how can I put some explicit dependencies on this?

The webapp and app insights sit in one module, the mongodb in a second, and both are called in the main.tf file.

Adding some extra code:

This is a part of the main.tf file, calling both modules

```
module "app_service" {
  source   = "./modules/app_service"
  for_each = var.web_apps

  primary_pipeline        = var.primary_pipeline
  lztri                   = var.lztri
  workload                = var.workload
  env                     = var.env
  stage                   = var.stage
  location                = var.location
  loc                     = var.loc
  tags                    = var.tags
  web_app_name            = each.key
  deploy_private_endpoint = each.value.deploy_private_endpoint
  deploy_app_insights     = each.value.deploy_app_insights
  resource_type           = "webapp"
  subnet_name             = var.private_endpoint_config["webapp"].subnet_name
  private_dns_zone_group  = var.private_endpoint_config["webapp"].private_dns_zone_group
  subresource_names       = var.private_endpoint_config["webapp"].subresource_names
  is_manual_connection    = var.private_endpoint_config["webapp"].is_manual_connection
}

module "mongodb" {
  source = "./modules/mongodb"

  primary_pipeline                                 = var.primary_pipeline
  lztri                                            = var.lztri
  workload                                         = var.workload
  env                                              = var.env
  stage                                            = var.stage
  location                                         = var.location
  loc                                              = var.loc
  tags                                             = var.tags
  atlas_api_pub_key                                = var.mongodb.atlas_api_pub_key
  atlas_api_pri_key                                = var.mongodb.atlas_api_pri_key
  is_collect_database_specifics_statistics_enabled = var.mongodb.is_collect_database_specifics_statistics_enabled
  is_data_explorer_enabled                         = var.mongodb.is_data_explorer_enabled
  is_extended_storage_sizes_enabled                = var.mongodb.is_extended_storage_sizes_enabled
  is_performance_advisor_enabled                   = var.mongodb.is_performance_advisor_enabled
  is_realtime_performance_panel_enabled            = var.mongodb.is_realtime_performance_panel_enabled
  is_schema_advisor_enabled                        = var.mongodb.is_schema_advisor_enabled
  num_shards                                       = var.mongodb.num_shards
  regions_config                                   = var.mongodb.regions_config
  cloud_backup                                     = var.mongodb.cloud_backup
  auto_scaling_disk_gb_enabled                     = var.mongodb.auto_scaling_disk_gb_enabled
  provider_name                                    = var.mongodb.provider_name
  provider_instance_size_name                      = var.mongodb.provider_instance_size_name
  web_apps                                         = var.web_apps
  allowed_ips                                      = var.mongodb.allowed_ips
  invited_users                                    = var.mongodb.invited_users
  #instrumentation_key                              = module.app_service.instrumentation_key

  depends_on = [module.app_service.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights]
}
```

As said in the comment, I'm setting the mongodb provider in the module, instead of in root, as this is not a default hashicorp provider. This makes it a legacy module. And this causes me not being able to use "depends_on" on the module.
I believe I'll have to find a way to make it non-legacy.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mongodbatlas = {
      source = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"
      version = "1.13.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "mongodbatlas" {
  public_key  = var.atlas_api_pub_key
  private_key = var.atlas_api_pri_key
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you deploy multi-tier applications, some resources may depend on the outputs of other resources. For example, a web server may need the IP address of a database server. If these resources are in different modules, you have to create explicit dependencies between these modules. You can do this by passing outputs from one module as inputs to another. You can also use the depends_on argument in your module configuration. This will help Terraform to have a better understanding of your configuration.

Comment: Indeed I already thought I would need a depends_on, but, I don't see how exactly I should do this. Do I put this on the mongodb resourceblock, or in the main.tf file, where I'm calling the module, or something else?

Comment: In module "mongodb" try adding depends_on = [module.webapp]. By  this you're telling Terraform that all resources within the MongoDB module depend on the completion of the resources defined in the web app module.

Comment: Do I do this on one specific resource? Because I noticed if I did it in the main, where the module is called, terraform wants it on a resource..

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code of your main.tf file

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman It will be helpful once you're share your terraform configuration to have a better understanding of your requirement.

Comment: @VinayB ,  I think I know what you mean, but, as I'm using mongodb, I had to specify the provider in the module itself, making it a legacy module. This means I can't use the depends_on on that module. So I guess I've got to find a way to make it not being legacy. Also, using an output to transfer the values is not an option, as the other module is ran multiple times with a for_each.  I'll add some extra pieces of code that can be helpful.

Comment: First time I've seen the term "legacy module" ... The only reason you can't use the `depends_on` on a module is if you have an old version of Terraform, (Module support for depends_on was added in Terraform version 0.13) if that is your case look at the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58277124/7599833

Comment: Looking at your code you have commented `instrumentation_key` that points to `module.app_service...` if you enable that, it will automatically create the correct dependency

Comment: @HelderSepulveda, I hadn't before eighter, a module becomes "legacy" when you specify its provider in the module itself instead of in the root file. I had to do this for the mongodb provider. 
The instrumentation key part is indeed commented, but because it didn't work, and in the end was not needed anymore. But for testing I tried enabling it, didn't work...

Comment: The provider is not the problem ... I mentioned before, the reason we can't use `depends_on` on a module is if we have an old version of Terraform, upgrade to latest and you should be good

Comment: I'm using the latest version 

Answer (score 0):

> Dependency issue with multiple Terraform modules deploying to Azure

Your text explains a frequent challenge in infrastructure as code (IaC) that arises from interdependencies among modules. This happens when some modules require resources that are provided by other modules. For example, the MongoDB module depends on resources that are not available yet: Application Insights and Linux Web App. The error messages indicate this dependency issue.

**Possible Solutions and Approach:**

1. **Explicit Dependencies with `depends_on`**: With `depends_on`, you can declare explicit dependencies between resources or modules in Terraform. However, this feature has some limitations when working with modules, especially legacy ones, as you observed.
2. **Refactor the Module Design:** A possible way to improve your modules is to refactor them to handle dependencies more effectively. You could create a common module where you can manage resource creation and dependencies more easily.
3. **Use Outputs as Inputs**:A possible way to manage these dependencies is to feed the results of one module into another as inputs.

   In your case, outputs from the `app_service` module can be passed as inputs to the `mongodb` module.

**Demo Terraform configuration:**

**main.tf:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mongodbatlas = {
      source = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"
      version = "1.13.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "resourcerg-vksb"
  location = "East US"
}

module "app_service" {
  source              = "./modules/app_service"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

module "mongodb" {
  source              = "./modules/mongodb"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  app_insights_id     = module.app_service.app_insights_id 
  web_app_id          = module.app_service.web_app_id
  depends_on          = [module.app_service]
}
```

**modules/app_service/main.tf:**

```
    variable "resource_group_name" {
      description = "The name of the resource group"
      type        = string
    }
    
    variable "location" {
      description = "The location/region of the resources"
      type        = string
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
      name                = "demovk-service-plan"
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
      os_type             = "Linux"
      sku_name            = "P1v2"
    
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
      name                = "demovk-appserviceplan"
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    
      sku {
        tier = "Standard"
        size = "S1"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_app_service" "web_app" {
      name                = "demovksb-linux-web-app"
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
      app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
    
      site_config {
        linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|<user/image:tag>"
        always_on        = true
      }
    
      app_settings = {
        "WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE" = "false"
      
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_application_insights" "app_insights" {
      name                = "demovk-app-insights"
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
      application_type    = "web"
    }
    
    output "app_service_id" {
      value = azurerm_app_service.web_app.id
    }
    
    output "app_insights_id" {
      value = azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.id
    }
```

**modules/mongodb/main.tf:**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The location/region of the resources"
  type        = string
}

variable "app_insights_id" {
  type = string
  description = "The ID of the Application Insights resource"
}

variable "web_app_id" {
  type = string
  description = "The ID of the Web App resource"
}



resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "mongodb" {
  name                = "demorgvk-mongodb-account"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"

  capabilities {
    name = "EnableMongo"
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "Session"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 10
    max_staleness_prefix    = 200
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = var.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, firstly thanks for the ellaborate answer, I had been looking into this kind of solution as well, but got stuck on the fact that my app_service module is called multiple times using a for_each, so I'm a bit stuck on how I can output a variable to the mongodb module.